# Keeping external application configuration centralized in Android

Tags: android

(Android-Noob)

I can't find a best approach for encapsulating configuration resources.

Basically I'd like to keep configuration values like these:

```xml
<string name="environment">dev</string> 
<integer name="lookup_timeout">750</integer> 
<boolean name="use_cache">true</boolean>
```

- all in one place,
- in a single xml-file
- accessible from Java through some kind of unified method (`R.config.environment`)

Anything I'm missing?

**Update**: What are configuration resources?

A set of values that typically is environment specific and will most probably change / being fine-tuned by the developer during application development. It is certainly not user-modifiable, and though has nothing to do with user-preferences.

Typical examples are:

- the general log level
- the place where logs are written to
- the urls of servers (development / integration / production)

C'mon, you must know what I mean ;-)

Comment: What is a "configuration resource"? Is it user-modifiable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A set of values that typically is environment specific and will most probably change / being fine-tuned during application development.

Your XML is almost verbatim what you can put in a values resource file. In your project's `res/values/` directory, create a `configuration_resource_that_is_environment_specific.xml` file (or whatever you wish to call it -- the name does not matter). In there, you can have [string](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html), [integer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer), and [boolean](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Bool) resources. You would retrieve those at runtime via a `Resources` object, which you can get via a call to `getResources()` from any `Context`, such as your `Activity`.

You can also then override those resource values via other resource sets (e.g., `res/values-v11/` for versions of those values that should be different for API Level 11+).

That being said, I think most people just store this stuff in static data members in Java for simplicity.

> C'mon, you must know what I mean ;-)

Not only is "configuration resource" unclear, but so is "environment specific", since we do not know what you consider your "environment" to be.

Comment: Thanks for answering. My background is Java Enterprise, and we typically have pretty complex build processes, that create different deployments for different environments (read: different servers). Storing configuration-related data in Java code is considered bad practice, because it requires the code to be compiled again for any changes. Guess it's not that complicated in Android :)

Comment: @jangroth: Well, since you aren't going to generate different builds for a million users of your app, the problem is simply different. There's nothing wrong with isolating these things in values resources, and if they do vary based on *Android* environment (OS version, screen size, etc.), using the resource framework can be a big win. Eventually (:: fingers crossed ::) we will also be able to declare resources as debug vs. production, which would get into your server URLs scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: thanks for answering, but I'm not looking for this. I updated the question accordingly.